# How to extend a class instance?

Tags: python, constructor

I have an instance..

```
groupCell = QtGui.QGroupBox()
print groupCell.title() #this class has a method title()
```

I am not able to change anything of this instance, it comes how it is...

I need to extend this instance (add some methods etc.)

```
class GroupBoxWithCheckbox (QtGui.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, basegroupbox, checkbox):
        #something like self = basegroupbox ?
        self.checkbox = checkbox
    def method(self):
        pass
```

and finally

```
groupCellWithCheckBox = GroupBoxWithCheckbox(groupCell, checkbox)
print groupCellWithCheckBox.title()
```

I have to get the same title as with groupCell.

Comment: You should just make `groupCell` an instance of the derived class.

Comment: Don't believe Python does eigen class

Comment: I am not able to do anything with groupCell, it comes how it is..

Comment: Then write that in the question, which is currently very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new class extending `QtGui.QGroupBox` that looks like this:

```
class GroupBoxWithCheckbox(QtGui.QGroupBox):

    def __init__(self, checkbox):
        super(GroupBoxWithCheckbox, self).__init__()
        self.checkbox = checkbox

    def method(self):
        pass
```

Then you can simply make `groupCell` an instance of *this* class, and pass in a checkbox when you initialise it:

```
groupCell = GroupBoxWithCheckbox(checkbox)
```

That will have the same effect as what you are trying to do here.

---

**Edit, since new information has been provided:**

Since we're talking Python here, you can dynamically add things to any instance you want. It's totally possible to do this:

```
groupCell.checkbox = checkbox
```

*Even if the groupCell doesn't have a checkbox property*. The property will be added when you set it, as in my snippet above. You could use that to do what you want. It's kind of a weird thing to do, and I don't recommend it, but it *would* work. The alternative is to make a wrapper class of some sort:

```
class GroupBoxWithCheckbox(object):
    def __init__(self, groupbox, checkbox):
        self.groupbox = groupbox
        self.checkbox = checkbox

groupCell = GroupBoxWithCheckbox(groupCell, checkbox)
```

And then any time you want to access a method of the original GroupBox, you can do something like

```
groupCell.groupbox.title()
```

`groupCell.groupbox` will contain *all* of the methods that the original GroupBox did, but you'll also have access to `groupCell.checkbox`.

The latter solution is what I would implement if I were coding this.

Comment: I am sorry, I did'nt notice,  I am not able to do anything with groupCell, it comes how it is - I've updated the question.

Comment: Ah, I thought you might have a restriction like that but was unsure. I'll see if I can come up with something, un momento.

Answer (score 0):

Call base class constructor using [`super`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

```
class GroupBoxWithCheckbox(QtGui.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, basegroupbox, checkbox):
        super(GroupBoxWithCheckbox, self).__init__()
        self.checkbox = checkbox
        self.basegroupbox = basegroupbox
    def title(self):
        return self.basegroupbox.title()
```

Comment: It doesn't work, please see the updated question, with your implementation I don't get the same title.

Comment: yes I understand, thats posible, but.. there are actually a lot of methods and variables, therefore I would like to inherits them..